# Compare List<string> and get the differences including empty value

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I'm trying to compare two `List<string>`. Just needed the items which is having *differences*

```
List<string> ExpectedList = new List<string>() { "apple","orange","grapes","mango"};
List<string> ActualList = new List<string>() { "gova","orange","GRAP"};
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(ExpectedList, ActualList)
```

**Expected results should be in String like below,**

```
"apple gova, grape GRAP, Mango empty"
```

How can I do it more *efficiently* or *simply*?

Comment: Assuming you are able to use LINQ then you could take a look at the _Except_ method. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Why is there a comma after `gova` but not after `grape`?

Comment: What would be the **exact** expected results if the first list was `{ "a", "b", "c" }` and the second was `{"a", "c", "e", "b"}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try *Linq* and `string.Join`:

```
  List<string> ExpectedList = new List<string>() { "apple", "orange", "grapes", "mango" };
  List<string> ActualList = new List<string>() { "gova", "orange", "GRAP" };

  string report = string.Join(", ", Enumerable
    .Range(0, Math.Max(ExpectedList.Count, ActualList.Count))
    .Select(i => new {
      expected = i < ExpectedList.Count ? ExpectedList[i] : null,
      actual = i < ActualList.Count ? ActualList[i] : null,
    })
    .Where(item => item.actual != item.expected)
    .Select(item => $"{item.expected ?? "empty"} {item.actual ?? "empty"}"));

  Console.Write(report);
```

**Outcome:**

```
apple gova, grapes GRAP, mango empty
```

If *both* `ExpectedList` and `ActualList` *don't have* special `"empty"` string you can put `report` shorter:

```
  string report = string.Join(", ", Enumerable
    .Range(0, Math.Max(ExpectedList.Count, ActualList.Count))
    .Select(i => new {
      expected = i < ExpectedList.Count ? ExpectedList[i] : "empty",
      actual = i < ActualList.Count ? ActualList[i] : "empty",
    })
    .Where(item => item.actual != item.expected)
    .Select(item => $"{item.expected} {item.actual}"));
```

Comment: Fantastic!!! works like a champ - thank you for your effort on this, Highly Appreciatable